# Morley triangle: Calculate 3rd point of triangle when you have two points and two angles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

I want to calculate x,y coordinates of Morley Triangle for given triangle:

[image]

Image source [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Morley_triangle.png) by Tosha; CC-By-SA

If I have the coordinates of the points I can calculate the angles of bigger triangles and the smaller triangles on the sides will have an angle / 3.

So to get the Morley triangle all I need is 3rd point of a triangle if I have two points and two angles. But I'm not sure how can I get that points x and y. I can't seem to find the answer on this Q&A.

Comment: The sine rule gets you the lengths of the two sides you don't have.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm not that proficient with analytic geometry, how can I get x,y coordinate if I have the length of the sides?

Comment: Well you have both the length and the direction (choose an axis to make life simple). So you get the equation of line which forms the side and compute the correct distance along.

Comment: @MarkBennet I think that if I have distance I can calculate the point between two points with a given distance and rotate it by a given angle.

Answer (score 3):

(see figure below, obtained with GeoGebra) :

Here is a solution giving providing the exact coordinates of the vertices of the Morley triangle.

First of all, WLOG, it is possible to consider that the triangle $ABC$ is inscribed into the unit circle (see Remark at the bottom).

The "astute" idea is to write $A=a^3, B=b^3, C=c^3$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ (Remark: I don't make any distinction between a point and its so-called "affix").

In this way, the points where the different line trisectors meet the unit circle can be expressed by $a^2,b^2a,\cdots$ (see the figure ; do you understand why ?).

Then, with some calculations, we get the following expressions of the vertices $u,v,w$ of the Morley triangle :

\begin{cases}
u&=&-b^2c-bc^2+ac^2+ab^2+abc\\
v&=&-c^2a\omega^2-ca^2\omega+ba^2+bc^2\omega^2+abc \omega\\
w&=&-a^2b \omega^2-ab^2 \omega + cb^2 \omega + ca^2 + abc \omega^2
\end{cases}

where $\omega$ stands for $e^{2i \pi/3}$.

All these calculations are adapted from a delicious 180 pages book written (in French) "Le Théorème de Morley" 1993, ADCS, by André Viricel, a late friend of mine.

Of course, the $(x,y)$ coordinates of $u,v,w$ are obtained by taking the real and imaginary parts of the expressions above.

---

**Animation :** one can upload the Geogebra file [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/sxjamsmm) and animate it by moving the little blue lozenges representing complex numbers $a,b,c$.

---

**Remark :** if the vertices of the initial triangle $T$ have the following complex representation : $z_1,z_2,z_3$, here is the "modus operandi".

It is possible to map $z_1,z_2,z_3$ onto points of the unit circle $z_1',z_2',z_3'$ by a certain transformation $f$ (translation + homothety) obtained in this way :

- Compute the circumcenter $z_C$ of $T$ which is such that :

$$z_C^2=\tfrac13(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2)$$

(caution in taking the complex square root : only one of the two solutions is the valid one).

- Then compute the radius of the circumcircle of $T$ : $r=|z_1-z_C|$.

The transformation is $z'=f(z)=\frac{1}{r}(z-z_C)e^{i \alpha}$.

(where $\alpha$ can take any value)

The complete chain of operations is

- apply $f$ to initial triangle $T$
- operate as we have done inside the unit circle
- apply $f^{-1}$ to the results in order to reintegrate them in the framework of the initial triangle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now all that is left is to write this down as code.

Comment: Just added the possibility to access the Geogebra animation.

Comment: A similar use of complex numbers [here](https://blog.evanchen.cc/2018/02/28/revisiting-arc-midpoints-in-complex-numbers/)