# Complex representation of orthocenter : a signed area issue.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, terminology, triangles

I was recently looking up an equation for the orthocenter in the complex plane and found the following in **Zwikker**, C. (1968), *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press:

$$z_O=\frac{z_1\{z_1(z_2^*-z_3^*)+z_1^*(z_2-z_3)\}+\text{cycl.}}{4iA}$$

where $^*$ denotes the conjugate and $A$ is the area. I've not encountered the term **cycl.** previously and assumed it meant cycling through the indices, such as $z_2,z_3,z_1$ and $z_3,z_1,z_2$. But this did not give the correct result.

Zwikker similarly give the circumcenter as

$$z_C=\frac{z_1z_1^*(z_3-z_2)+\text{cycl.}}{4iA}$$

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you have given (page 53 of the mentioned [book](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/475961.pdf)) with its "cycl." is indeed to be interpreted as you have done.

One can re-write it under the equivalent form :

$$z_O=\frac{1}{2iA}\left[a_1z_1+a_2z_2+a_3z_3\right]  \ \text{with} \  \begin{cases}a_1&=&\Re(\overline{z_1}(z_2-z_3))\\ a_2&=&\Re(\overline{z_2}(z_3-z_1))\\a_3 &=&\Re(\overline{z_3} (z_1-z_2))\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

This formula **works** in all cases provided that

$$A:=\frac12 \Im(z_1 \overline{z_2}+z_2 \overline{z_3}+z_3 \overline{z_1}),\tag{2}$$

is interpreted as the **opposite** of the signed area of triangle $z_1z_2z_3$ in the universally accepted anti-clockwise orientation. As well explained by Blue in his comment, the author takes, oddly, the clockwise orientation as the default orientation.

Remark: ($\Re$ and $\Im$ stand for "real part", and "imaginary part" resp.).

Here is a GeoGebra animation based on formulas (1) and (2) displaying the orthocenter (red point) of any kind of triangle (one can move the sliders giving the real and imaginary parts $a_k$ and $b_k$ of points $z_k$ ; you have to move up the lift in the left window to make the sliders viewable).

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/jj5zmqsg

Please note that if $z_1,z_2,z_3$ all belong to the unit circle, there exists a much simpler formula which is :

$$z_O=z_1+z_2+z_3$$

(see [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/OrthocenterInComplexPlane.shtml))

Comment: The formula works, but only if area $A$ is *signed*: *positive* when $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ go *clockwise* around the triangle, and *negative* otherwise. (You can check in the Desmos project, which uses *unsigned* area, that the calculated (ostensible) orthocenter for counter-clockwise triangles is the reflection in the origin of the true orthocenter; that is, its corresponding complex value has a sign error.) That's a little unexpected; hadn't the mathematical community decided by the 1960s that *counter-clockwise* was the preferred orientation? :)

Comment: @Blue Excellent remark. I hadn't foreseen this aspect of the question, having the reflex to take always this counter-clockwise orientation for my polygons...

Comment: @Blue I have fixed the issue.

Comment: There is something wrong here. The way you have written the equation for $z_O$ it would always be purely imaginary.

Comment: You are right : the expression is good on GeoGebra but I have added a $\Re$ in (1) which has nothing to do there ! I erase it !

Comment: Also, in the matter of signed area, if I gave you three random positions you don't know that there are in anti-clockwise order, so it would be safer to take the abs value of that expression. The same is true for the determinant form that I sometimes use, $det([1\  1\  1; z1\  z2\  z3;z1^* \ z2^*\  z3^*]$

Comment: About the determinant form, yes it also this one I am familiar with (multiplied by $i/4$). I needed to expand it in the form (2) in order it is "digestible" by Geogebra.

Comment: @Cye Waldman As you are interested by complex number geometry (as I am), here is a very recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612993/305862) which I have found interesting.

Comment: ... and another (also very recent one) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4611944/305862)

Comment: ... and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4595207/305862), a month ago, containing a reference to Evan Chen's blog.

Comment: The present title could be changed into something more adapted  like "Complex representation of orthocenter : a signed area issue". This would allow much more future queries to "trigger" this question.